# how to redirect to a link with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to redirect a user to a link provided by me using `window.loction.herf` or `window.location.assgin` but I think I miss something

the source of information I am learning from is w3schools
[w3schools window.location.herf](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp)

I have a simple java script that redirects to google.com but I does not show anything just a blank webpage and when i view the source page I can't see any reference to google.com

[my example](https://PopularQualifiedEmacs--five-nine.repl.co)

Comment: Maybe Conflict is on href and herf

Comment: You have a typo: `herf` should be `href`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check you write herf instead href, maybe thats the problem

```js
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
```

Comment: Don't post real answers for typos. Just comment and vote to close using the typo reason.

Answer (score 2):

You have written "herf" instead of "href"

```
<script> 
      window.location.herf="https://www.google.com/"
    </script>
```

change this to:

```
<script> 
      window.location.href="https://www.google.com/"
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a type between `herf` and `href`.

However,

`window.location.replace(...)` is a better alternate for `href` due to the reason that the browser would not keep the originating page in the session history.